# How can i change already generated angular app with css stylesheet - to use scss

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have generated angular app to use css - which is default one. After that i see that the project will grow in the future and i wanted to use next components with scss stylesheet.

I edited that in my angular.json file

```
 "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
```

previous was -  "styleext": "css"

i restarded the server, i tried to generate new component with

```
ng g c some-new-compo
```

but now angular cli generated again the component with css stylesheet instead with scss

I am using angular 10 version.

How this needs to be done ?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://indepth.dev/posts/1330/migrate-from-css-to-scss-stylesheets-for-an-existing-angular-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following command to change angular config

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.style scss
```

and open `angular.json` file

Change your

```
"schematics": {}
```

to

```
"schematics": {
     "@schematics/angular:component": {
           "styleext": "scss"       
      }     
 }
```

change from (at two places)

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css"
 ],
```

to

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
 ],
```

Then change manually all you component `.css` to `.scss` and change in the `.ts` files as follows in config

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

and then create a component it will create `.scss` file as you expected

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. Foe angular version 9+ it needs to be: style insteadm styleext

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
```